# Efficiently clearing flatbuffer builders for layers of tables

Tags: flatbuffers

Can I reuse 'sub' builder instances generated from a `flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder` after calling `builder.Clear()`? What is the effect of `builder.Clear()` on sub-builders?

Having generated a flatbuffers schema such as the following:

```
table FB_mytable1{
myshort::ushort = 0;
}
table FB_table2{
nestedTable1::FB_mytable1;
nestedTable1::FB_mytable1;
}
root_type FB_table2;
```

If I reset the builder using `builder.clear()`, my instantiation of 'flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder', will this allow me to generate new serial data without calling a reset function or renewing any of the individual table serialisers, such as my instantiation of `FB_mytable1Builder myFB_mytable1Builder(builder)`? Or do I need to ensure that the individual builder objects have a scope that means they are not reused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clear()` resets a `FlatBufferBuilder` as if just constructed, and any of the table builder instances should not be reused across multiple buffers or even multiple tables.

See, a `FlatBufferBuilder` is a somewhat heavyweight structure (since it owns a buffer), so it makes sense to reuse it when you can. The table builders however are super lightweight, so should just be a local variable used for construction of a single table, you can't reuse them.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to understand my question. I will update it to better describe the question that you have answered for me, which was indeed what I needed to know.

Comment: Ok, removed "Not entirely sure what you're asking" from my answer :)